# Can I get stable 4K 60Hz with two external displays without MBP screen on? What about performance with MBP15 mid-2015DG

Tags: macbook-pro, display, performance, dual-screen, 4k

I want to buy two 24 or 27 inch monitors for work (Xcode, Sketch, Android/Visual Studio) with high screen resolution. I'm worried about performance with my notebook (MBP 15" mid-2015 DG, 16GB RAM, Radeon M370x 2GB VRAM).

I'm thinking about two 4K displays LG 27UD58-B or two 1440p Lenovo ThinkVision L24q-10.

My choice depends on the MBP performance with two 4k monitors.

Does anyone have this configuration and can help me?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) We've had to put your question on hold as it's currently too broad. However, if you [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/304712/edit) your question to narrow it down to the specifics, we can then review this. For example, providing details of the exact models of display you're looking at and restricting the question to something like *Can I connect my x model Mac to two y model displays?* is more likely to get relevant answers. Try also to avoid asking something that is opinion-based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> #### Can I get stable 4K 60Hz with two external displays without MBP screen on?

Your internal screen of your MBP being on/off doesn't factor into whether the MBP can support 2 external 4K displays

According to the [specifications page](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP715?locale=en_US) for the mid-2015 MacBook Pro:

> Dual display and video mirroring: Simultaneously supports full native
> resolution on the built-in display and up to 3840 by 2160 pixels on up
> to two external displays, both at millions of colors.

This means it will support two external displays at [4K (UHD) resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4K_resolution).

**But at 60Hz?**

According to Apple Support document [Using 4K displays, 5K displays, and Ultra HD TVs with your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206587)

> If you use a 60Hz MST display with the MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch,
> Mid 2015) with AMD Radeon R9 M370X graphics card or iMac (Retina 5K,
> 27-inch, Late 2014), only one additional Thunderbolt display is
> supported.

Yes it will support it, but only one more display connected to the *Thunderbolt* port will be supported - you can connect two displays.

**Do those monitors support MST?**

The [LG 27UD58-B](http://www.lg.com/us/support-product/lg-27UD58-B) supports DisplayPort 1.2 (MST capable) per their [specifications](http://www.lg.com/us/support/products/documents/27UD58-B_Spec_Sheet_20170921.pdf).  I haven't researched the Lenovo monitor.

> #### What about performance with MBP15 mid-2015DG

Given that the monitors are supported, your MacBook Pro should perform as expected.  Keep in mind, performance is a subjective description - what performs to expectation for one person may fall short for another.